# On the weighted adjacency matrix of a directed acyclic graph (DAG)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, adjacency-matrix

A matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is the weighted adjacency matrix  of a directed acyclic graph (DAG) if and only if

$$ h(W) = \operatorname{tr} \left( \exp(W \circ W ) \right) - d = 0 $$

where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product and $\exp(A)$ is the matrix exponential of $A$. Moreover, $h(W)$ has a simple gradient

$$\nabla h(W) = (e^{W \circ W})^T \circ 2W$$

---

**My proof**

To obtain the gradient of the function $h(W)$ with respect to the matrix $W$, we can apply standard matrix calculus techniques.

Take the derivative of $h(W)$ with respect to each element of the matrix $W$. When we compute the derivative of a function with respect to a matrix, such as $\frac{\partial h(W)}{\partial W}$, we need to take into account that each element of the matrix $W$ is a separate variable. In the context of the gradient, we want to find the derivative with respect to the entire matrix $W$, resulting in a matrix of the same size as $W$ representing the gradient. The entry in the gradient matrix corresponding to the element $W_{ij}$ is the partial derivative $\frac{\partial h(W)}{\partial W_{ij}}$.

To compute the derivative of the trace term $\text{tr}(e^{W \circ W})$, I find this reference is useful: \url{http://paulklein.ca/newsite/teaching/matrix%20calculus.pdf}

$\frac{\partial \text{tr}(f(W))}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial \text{tr}(f(W))}{\partial f(W)} \frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W}$ , where $f(W)$ is a matrix function of $W$. In this case, $f(W) = e^{W \circ W}$.

By using the equation (9) from the above reference, we can see that $ \frac{\partial \text{tr}(f(W))}{\partial f(W)}  = I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

We are left to compute $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W}$.

Let $M = W \circ W$. Express $f(W)$ in terms of $M$: $f(W) = e^M$.

Differentiate $f(W)$ with respect to $M$: $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M} = \frac{\partial e^M}{\partial M}$.

Apply the derivative of the matrix exponential function: $\frac{\partial e^M}{\partial M} = e^M$.

Replace $M$ with $W \circ W$ in the expression: $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M} = e^{W \circ W}$.

Finally, we have $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M} \cdot \frac{\partial (W \circ W)}{\partial W}$.

Compute the derivative of $(W \circ W)$ with respect to $W$. Since the Hadamard product is element-wise, we have $\frac{\partial (W \circ W)}{\partial W} = 2W$.

Multiply $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial M}$ with $\frac{\partial (W \circ W)}{\partial W}$: $\frac{\partial f(W)}{\partial W} = e^{W \circ W} \cdot 2W$.

But in the original paper, the result is $(e^{W \circ W})^T \circ 2W$. Which step that I get wrong?

Comment: What kind of matrix is $W$? Is it any matrix or is it an adjacency matrix of a graph (and therefore  symmetric?).

Comment: What does DAG stands for (directed acyclic graph?) and what is $d$? If I pick $d=\operatorname{tr}(e^{W \circ W})$, isn't every square matrix DAG???

Comment: @ejk W is weighted adjacency matrix of a graph. It doesn't need to be symmetric.

Comment: Assuming the exponential is an element-wise function, the result from the paper is almost correct, except for the transpose operation. This becomes obvious when $W$ is rectangular instead of square.

Comment: On the other hand, if the exponential is the standard (matrix-wise) function, then the result from the paper is correct. But this only holds when $W$ is square.

Comment: Why not use `\exp`?  Would make it more readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\eqalign{
X &= W\odot W \\
dX &=2W\odot dW  \qquad\quad \{{\rm differential}\} \\
E &= e^X \;\,\equiv\;\, I + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k!} X^k\\
dE &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k X^{k-j}\;dX\;X^{j-1} \\
\\
h &= \operatorname{trace}(E) \\
 &= I:E  \qquad\;\; \{{\rm matrix\;inner\;product}\} \\
dh &= I:dE \\
  &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k X^{k-j}\;I\;X^{j-1}\right)^T:dX \\
  &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(k-1)!}X^{k-1}\right)^T:dX \\
  &= E^T:dX \\
  &= E^T:(2W\odot dW) \\
  &= (2E^T\odot W):dW \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial W} &= 2E^T\odot W \\
}$$

---

Element-wise exponential
$$\eqalign{
E_{ij} &= e^{X_{ij}} \\
dE_{ij} &= E_{ij}\;dX_{ij} \\
dE &= E\odot dX \\
dh &= I:dE \\
   &= E:dX \\
   &= E:(2W\odot dW) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \\
   &= (2E\odot W):dW \\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial W} &= 2E\odot W \\
}$$

Comment: can you explain the step $dX =2W\odot dW $?

Comment: The Hadamard product is commutative, so you can collect terms 
$$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
dX = W\odot\c{dW} \;+\; \c{dW}\odot W \;\equiv\; 2W\odot\c{dW}
$$
On the other hand, Matrix and Kronecker products are not commutative 
$$\eqalign{
dM &= W\cdot\c{dW} \;&+\;\; \c{dW}\cdot W &\ne 2W\cdot\c{dW} \\
dK &= W\otimes\c{dW} \;&+\;\; \c{dW}\otimes W &\ne 2W\otimes\c{dW} \\
}$$

Comment: Can you explain the step $dE = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k X^{k-j}\;dX\;X^{j-1}$?

Comment: Consider the differential a simple polynomial function
$$\large\eqalign{
P &= X^3 = XXX \\
dP &= XX\;dX + X\;dX\;X + dX\;XX \\
 &= X^2\,dX\;X^0 + X\;dX\;X + X^0\,dX\;X^2 \\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^3 X^{3-j}\;dX\;X^{j-1} \\
}$$